# IIF Function in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I am trying to write an IIF statement to return on certain Job Titles in my Query.

However, when I went to run my code, this column did not even get returned in the table that I created. I looked online and it seems that this is the correct syntax. Am I missing something that is causing it not to return this column?

```
IIF ([w.Job_Title] = "Sales Pro" OR [w.Job_Title] = "Services Pro" OR [w.Job_Title] = "Universal Pro" OR [w.Job_Title] = "Fulfillment Pro", "JobTitle", NULL),
```

I originally had a WHERE statement at the end of my query, but this seemed to cause my other data to not be accurate, so I thought this IIF way would be better.

Below is the Full query:

```
SELECT cal.FiscalYear,
       cal.FiscalQuarter,
       cal.FiscalMonth,
       cal.FiscalWeekNumber,
       Format(w.Day, "Dddd") AS DayOfWeek,
       cal.Day AS CalendarDay,
       w.Day,
       c.SegStart,
       c.SPLITNAME AS SkillName,
       w.Site,
       w.Campaign,
       w.Manager,
       w.Supervisor,
       IIF ([w.Job_Title] = "Sales Pro"
            OR [w.Job_Title] = "Services Pro"
            OR [w.Job_Title] = "Universal Pro"
            OR [w.Job_Title] = "Fulfillment Pro", "JobTitle", NULL),
       w.EmployeeNumber AS SalesID,
       w.ACDID,
       c.CallID,
       w.Employee,
       c.Caller_Name AS cms_EmployeeName,
       c.Answerer_Name AS cms_ProEmployeeName,
       c.Answered,
       c.AcwTime,
       c.Agt_Released AS AgentReleased,
       c.AnsHoldTime,
       c.AnsLogin,
       c.Calling_Pty AS CallingParty,
       c.Conference,
       c.ConsultTime,
       c.Dialed_Num AS DialedNumber,
       c.DispIVector,
       c.DispSplit,
       c.DispVDN,
       c.Duration,
       c.Disposition,
       c.Held,
       c.HoldABN AS AbanOnHold,
       c.OrigLogin,
       c.QueueTime,
       c.RingTime,
       c.TalkTime,
       c.Transferred,
       c.VDN2,
       c.VDN3,
       c.VDN4,
       c.VDN5
FROM (t_wfm AS w
      INNER JOIN t_cms AS c ON (c.CALLING_PTY = w.ACDID)
        AND (Format(c.SEGSTART, "Short date") = Format(w.[Day], "Short date")))
INNER JOIN tbl_Calendar AS cal ON cal.Day = w.Day;
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of data and expected results?

Comment: I am expecting the Job Titles to only return those above. In the sample of data, this column is not returned at all.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description. -- Also please post the full query.

Comment: See full query above

Comment: The query is just one to retrieve data from two tables, the only thing I am trying to get it to do is filter down to just retrieving certain Job Titles

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a column alias.

The column is most probably there, but with a title like `Expr1` or something.

I think what you want is retrieving the actual title, not the constant `"JobTitle"`:

```
   IIF ([w.Job_Title] = "Sales Pro"
        OR [w.Job_Title] = "Services Pro"
        OR [w.Job_Title] = "Universal Pro"
        OR [w.Job_Title] = "Fulfillment Pro", [w.Job_Title], NULL) AS JobTitle,
```

**Edit**

If you want to only return the **rows** containing these titles, the check goes into the WHERE clause. The `IIf()` is not needed then.

```
WHERE ([w.Job_Title] = "Sales Pro"
        OR [w.Job_Title] = "Services Pro"
        OR [w.Job_Title] = "Universal Pro"
        OR [w.Job_Title] = "Fulfillment Pro")
```

Comment: Ok that returned just the Job Titles that I want. I guess the Null then left what used to be other job title descriptions to be blank. How do I get it to return only those job titles and nothing else, not even Blanks where other Job Titles used to be? Would I use 'False' instead of Null? This is my first month use MS Access so I am trying to get the hang of it